# How to find the all the solutions of the linear iterated integer equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have following problem which needs some special tricks. Let $a_1=2, b_1=b_2=1$

define $$ a_n=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}$$ $$ b_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$$ $$ c_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$$ then how can we find general $a_n, b_n,c_n$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Isn't there a mistake ? the formula for $b_n$ is the same that the one for $c_n$

Comment: There is no mistake! I want to find a uniform method to solve similar problems. We note that this equation group can be represented by a matrix and we can use the Jordan form to find the solution, but this idea is too complicated!

Comment: Well as you noted, the idea is to be able to calculate $M^n$, where $M$ is the matrix of the system. Depending on $M$, it can be easy or not.

Comment: Yes, exactly. We note that if there is only one equation, for example $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, then we can solve the eqution $x^2=2x+1$. So my idea is that if we can implement similar idea for several linear equations, it would be great!

Comment: There's a method that uses generating functions, but it is very complicated.  I'm guessing that you're looking for something much simpler.  However, if you're interested, I could post a long answer.

Comment: I will appreciate you if you give me the method of generating function. I remember it uses power series.

Comment: For this problem, I have a good idea! Let $x_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$, then we sum the three equations and we can find $b_n$ and $c_n$ hence we can find $a_n$!